# Sum of reciprocals of $\phi(n)$

Tags: inequality, analytic-number-theory, totient-function

Let $Q$ be the set of square-free integers less than some $n$ and let $\phi$ denote the Euler totient.

I am currently reading an article where it is mentioned that :

$$\sum_{q\in Q}\frac1{\phi(k)}\ge\ln(n)$$

I would like to understand where that inequality does come from. Any hint ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

Note, merely for curiosity's sake, that one may actually obtain the asymptotic formula
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu^2(n)}{\varphi(n)} = \log x + c + o(1),$$
where
$$c = \gamma + \sum_{p} \frac{\log p}{p(p-1)} = 1.332\ldots.$$
Therefore the desired inequality follows for all $x$ sufficiently large, and if one had explicit bounds for the error term you could potentially do a machine computation to check the remaining cases.

We don't need any of this, however. The key observation is that, for $n$ squarefree, we have
$$\frac{1}{\varphi(n)} = \frac{1}{n}\prod_{p|n} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{p}} = \frac{1}{n}\prod_{p|n} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p^2} + \cdots \right) = \sum_{\substack{m \geq 1 \\ \text{rad}(m) = n}} \frac{1}{m}.$$
Here $\text{rad}(m)$ denotes the squarefree [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) of $m$, i.e.
$$\text{rad}(m) = \prod_{p|m} p.$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu^2(n)}{\varphi(n)} = \sum_{n \leq x} \mu^2(n)\sum_{\substack{m \geq 1 \\ \text{rad}(m) = n}} \frac{1}{m} \geq \sum_{k \leq x} \frac{1}{k}.$$
This inequality is the key step, but we see almost immediately it is true, since if $k \leq x$ then $\text{rad}(k) \leq x$. At this point we are basically done, since from elementary geometric considerations we have
$$\sum_{k \leq x} \frac{1}{k} \geq \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt = \log x.$$

Comment: I understand that $\sum_{n\le x}\mu^2(n)t_n$ is equal to $\sum t_n$, where this last sum is indexed by the set of squarefree integers not larger than $x$. Is there a standard notation for this in analytic number theory ? Something in the spirit of $\sum_{p\le x}$ for a sum indexed by the primes not larger than $x$ ?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the asymptotic expansion you mentioned a the beginning ?

Comment: @Adren See Lemma 2.3 in the paper "On an error term of Landau-II" by Sitaramachandrarao. You can find the paper at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1250127232.