# Showing $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{\phi (n)} = C\log x + O(1).$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, totient-function

In the first page of [this document](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250127232) by Sitaramachandrarao it is written that
$$\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{\phi (n)} = A( \log x + B) + E_0 (x) $$ and
$$ \sum_{n\leq x} \frac{n}{\phi (n)} = Ax - \frac{1}{2} \log x + E_1 (x),$$
where $$E_0 (x) = O\left( \frac{\log x}{x} \right) , A = \frac{315 \zeta (3)}{2\pi ^4} \text{ and } B = \gamma - \sum_{p} \frac{\log p}{p^2 - p +1},$$ where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function and $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant (I could not find what $E_1(x)$ denotes, so I think it denotes 
$O\left( \frac{\log x}{x} \right)$. To this end, is there a way to deduce that

> $$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{\phi (n)} = C\log x + O(1), \qquad{} C = \sum \frac{1}{n \phi (n)}$$

where the last sum equal to $C$ ranges over all square-free integers? We know that $$\sum_{d|n}\frac{\mu^2(d)}{\phi(d)} =\frac{n}{\phi(n)}$$ (I can attach a proof if needed) and also $$ \sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{\varphi(n)} = \sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} = O\left(\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}\right) = O(\log n).$$
I also found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192770/sum-of-reciprocals-of-phin) which says we can obtain the asymptotic formula
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{\mu^2(n)}{\varphi(n)} = \log x + c + o(1),$$
where
$$c = \gamma + \sum_{p} \frac{\log p}{p(p-1)} = 1.332\ldots.$$

Comment: I wonder what your questions are. It seems to me that your questions are answered in the paper by Sitaramachandrarao

Comment: @i707107 Instead of $\frac{315 \zeta (3)}{2\pi ^4} \log x$ I wanted to see if we could achieve $ \left( \sum \frac{1}{n \phi (n)} \right) \log x$

Comment: So, your question is "Why is $\frac{315\zeta(3)}{2\pi^4} = \sum \frac 1{n\phi(n)}$?

Comment: Also, the sum on the right is restricted to square free numbers, so it is really $\sum \frac{\mu^2(n)}{n\phi(n)}$.

Comment: @i707107 Yes, that is my question.

Comment: Estimates for $E_1(x)$ are given on pages 584 and 585 of the paper: $E_1(x)=\Omega(\log\log x)$ and $E_1(x)=\mathcal{O}(\log^{2/3}x)$, respectively. So $E_1(x)=\mathcal{O}(\log x/x)$ is definitely incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euler's product gives
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(\mu^2/\varphi)(n)}{n^s}=\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{1}{(p-1)p^s}\right) $$
from which
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(\mu^2/\varphi)(n)}{n}=\prod_{p}\frac{p^2-p+1}{p(p-1)}=\prod_p\frac{p^3+1}{p(p^2-1)}=\prod_{p}\frac{(p^6-1)}{p(p^2-1)(p^3-1)}=\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}{\zeta(6)}$$
and the RHS equals $\frac{315\,\zeta(3)}{2\pi^4}$ as wanted.

Comment: Damn, Jack, you do nice stuff!