# Find asymptotic formula for $\sum\limits_{n\le x} \frac{1}{\phi(n)}$ where $\phi$ is Euler's Phi function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, analysis, totient-function, mobius-function

I know (and proved) an identity
$$\frac{1}{\phi(n)}=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)^2}{\phi(d)}$$

Using this I got-

$\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{n\le x} \frac{1}{\phi(n)}}$

$\displaystyle{=\sum\limits_{n\le x} \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)^2}{\phi(d)}}$

$\displaystyle{=\sum\limits_{d\le x}\frac{\mu(d)^2}{\phi(d)}\sum\limits_{m\le x/d}\frac{1}{md}}$

$\displaystyle{=\sum\limits_{d\le x}\frac{\mu(d)^2}{d\phi(d)}\sum\limits_{m\le x/d}\frac{1}{m}}$

$\displaystyle{=\sum\limits_{d\le x}\frac{\mu(d)^2}{d\phi(d)}(\log (x/d)+\gamma+O(1/x))}$ where $\displaystyle{\gamma=1-\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{\{t\}}{t^2}\ dt}$

But now to proceed, I need to find asymptotic formula for $\displaystyle{\sum\limits_{d\le x}\frac{\mu(d)^2}{\phi(d)}}$. Can anyone help me with this? There is an explicit comutation of this in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2684083/515312) , but I'm not aware of the concept Euler product. Although I just need an asymptotic formula instead explicit value.

Is there any alternative way out to this? Can anyone help me in this regard/

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: There is a paper proving the asymptotic formula you seek directly from the Wikipedia page on the totient function: https://doi.org/10.1216%2FRMJ-1985-15-2-579

Comment: Sorry, saying "but I'm not aware of the concept Euler product" for this topic is like saying, "but I am not aware of the concept of a prime number" for a divisibility question in elementary number theory.